# How to delete an individual newsletter signup inside a .each loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to implement a delete button for each newsletter signup on my Users Show view in an admin section.

What I'm trying now:

```
<% @news_subs&.each do |news| %>
  <div class="vert-flip bot-drop">
    <div class="wellington bot-drop sub-well flip-card-inner">
      <div class="flip-card-front">
        <p class="align-left left hype"><%= news.name %></p>
        <p class="align-right right"><%= news.verified %></p>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="flip-card-back">
        <p class="newsletter-email"><%= news.email %></p>
        <%= link_to "Remove", news, method: :delete,
                                    data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to..." },
                                    class: "btn btn-xs btn-danger newsletter-remove" %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

But I am getting the following error:

> Routing Error
>
> No route matches [DELETE] "/newsletter.2"

I have tried using: `<%= link_to "Remove", Newsletter.find(params[:id]), method: :delete,` but that just throws the same error as well.

How can I delete the individual `news_sub` and not navigate away from the page?

Using Ruby 3 and Rails 6.1

**Update:**

Rails Routes:

```
                    newsletter_index GET    /newsletter(.:format)                                                                             newsletter#index
                                     POST   /newsletter(.:format)                                                                             newsletter#create
                      new_newsletter GET    /newsletter/new(.:format)                                                                         newsletter#new
                     edit_newsletter GET    /newsletter/:id/edit(.:format)                                                                    newsletter#edit
                                     GET    /newsletter/:id(.:format)                                                                         newsletter#show
                                     PATCH  /newsletter/:id(.:format)                                                                         newsletter#update
                                     PUT    /newsletter/:id(.:format)                                                                         newsletter#update
                                     DELETE /newsletter/:id(.:format)                                                                         newsletter#destroy
              edit_news_verification GET    /news_verification/:id/edit(.:format)                                                             news_verification#edit
```

Routes.rb:

```
get 'newsletter',                  to: 'newsletter#newsWelcome', as: 'newsWelcome'
post 'newsletter',                 to: 'newsletter#create'

...

resources :newsletter
resources :news_verification,                only: [:edit]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix this by specifying the route rather than just passing the object to your `link_to` method. Instead of passing `news` specify the path you need, eg `news_sub_path(news)`.

This should work:

```
<%= link_to "Remove", news_sub_path(news), method: :delete,
       data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to..." },
       class: "btn btn-xs btn-danger newsletter-remove" %>
```

Comment: Can you run `rake routes` and add the output to your question? Maybe also post the content of your `routes.rb` file

Comment: OK, try changing your route to be `resources :newsletters` (plural), and then use the route `newsletter_path(news)` in your `link_to`

Comment: OK - you've got some manual routes for newsletter in there at the top. Comment those out, so you only have the `resources :newsletters` in your `routes.rb` and try again.

Comment: It worked! Only had to comment out `post 'newsletter'` from my routes. It turned out I had my newsletters controller named `NewsletterController`, not plural which solved an additional error that got thrown up after changing it.

Comment: Awesome, congrats! :)